# Can't find the equivalent resistance in this circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistance

[image]

I'm trying to self-study this problem. This chapter explained the delta-to-y transformation but I can't seem to find one here.

My best guess is that both resistors on the right are short-circuited which gives them a value of 0. Then you add the two 3 ohm resistor on the left together, and thus the answer 6 ohms.

But I don't know if this is true.

Comment: To me, the answer is 7 Ohms. The 3 resistors to the right are in parallel with each other and can be redrawn as such if you move the two rightmost nodes to the left (over the vertical resistor terminals).

Comment: @Ricardo, sounds correct. I didn't picture them in parallel.

Comment: All 'internal' nodes are at the same potential, hence shorted.

Comment: @copper.hat I can see it now.

Comment: @Ricardo: I made the same mistake.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're right. The three resistors 3 \$\Omega\$, are shorted, so that the equivalent resistance is the sum 3 + 3 = 6.

[image]

Comment: Ok, I'm lost now. There are two different answers :P

Comment: They're not shorted, they're in parallel.

Comment: @Null: They are in parallel **and** shorted.

Comment: I can't see it. How are they shorted? To me the answer is 7 Ohms.

Comment: @Ricardo: Look at the outer edges. All 'internal' nodes are shorted together. (I fell for it too!)

Comment: @copper.hat Ah, yes. Whoever draws schematics like this should be shot.

Comment: @Null: I know, I was 'certain' about my 7 answer for a while.

Comment: @Null This is simply an educational schematic to practice on.

Comment: @hryghr I know, but it relies on a deliberately confusing drawing. Errors would be almost certain if someone drew schematics like this for real circuits.

Comment: @Null Everyone's gotta learn the tricks though.

Answer (score 3):

**This answer is wrong,** *as pointed out by Tinchito, but I'm leaving it here shamelessly for didactic reasons, as it seems as the most common mistake when looking quickly at the circuit.*

At first sight, you think you could redraw the schematic as follows (but you can't):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWlm8B.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If that was the case, then,

$$R3||R4||R5 = 1 \Omega$$

and

$$R_{eq} = R1 + R2 + (R3||R4||R5) = 7 \Omega$$

Looking closer you'll see that there's a zero resistance path that shorts out all three resistors, as pointed out by Tinchito, making the correct answer \$6 \Omega\$.

Comment: It fooled me for a while - I misread it like you did!!

Comment: @Andy - Yeah, it fooled many others here, too, it seems. That's probably the intention of the circuit's original author. I bet he or she could be a magician or illusionist.